# How to play sounds in lightdm greeter?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, lightdm

I am writing my own greeter for lightdm based on https://github.com/surlykke/qt-lightdm-greeter.

I wanna to play sounds to notify user if the password is not right for authentication.

I use alsa to play sounds and this works fine when I have already logged in, but on the system login screen I can not play the sounds and get this error:

`Can't open audio default: No such file or directory.`

I use snd_pcm_open to open the audio device and pass "default" as the device  name.
It seems like the audio device does not load if I am not log in.

Comment: So you use alsa to play sounds, but you have tagged pulseaudio. Is pulseaudio running then and if it is, as which user? I just noticed, that if I use ssh connection or just login using a TTY from lightdm greeter, I have two instances of pulseaudio running: one as the logged in user and one as lightdm.